# Convert CURL to Zapier Webhook Post

Tags: curl, webhooks, zapier

Please help, I cannot figure this out.

How do I perform the following CURL command using a Zapier Webhook Post:

```
curl 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC435d9f886af99bd30e4b0809d83c1db0/Messages.json' -X POST \
--data-urlencode 'To=whatsapp:+27721111015' \
--data-urlencode 'From=whatsapp:+14155238886' \
--data-urlencode 'Body=Your appointment is coming up on July 21 at 3PM' \
-u AC435d9f886af99bd30esdfg09d83c1db0:1772ce257sdfg6fe069accf83f2b8b47
```

Comment: Zapier handles the url encoding, so you should be able to paste `whatsapp:+277...` into each body field.

Comment: Also, I hope those credentials (`AC4...`) are either placeholders or inactive, since they're now posted on the public internet. I'd double check your twilio usage